# Form datasource only loads a part of records at a time?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, dynamics-ax-2009

Today I'm wondering why (AX2009) LedgerTransVoucher form only seems to load a part of query results at the time. If the results include, say, 35K rows, only 10k are loaded at once. And if the user decides to print the results to Excel, they would only get 10k rows.

Why is this? The 10k is such a clean number I'm thinking a parameter somewhere but I have no idea where it could be hidden.

And yes, I know they should be using a report instead :)

Comment: Are you sure the form loads 10k records? I would expect this number to be much lower, something in the lower 2 digits region. Export to Excel should normally include all possible records, but there are some [limits](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2015/11/23/limitations-of-the-export-to-excel-functionality-in-ax-2012/) that might be the cause of your described behavior. For such a big number of records, export to Excel might not be the right solution to your problem.

Comment: 10k is what I was told by the DBA. I am Jon Snow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, this apparently had nothing to do with AX as such, but is some conflict with Citrix. False alarm it seems.